# Pear DB method similar to bindParam()?

Tags: php, pear

Is there any way using the PEAR DB library to do something similar to the PDO `bindParam()`? I have a couple prepared statements that are going to use the same variable multiple times so I'd like to be able to bind the value to the variable in the prepared statement. I just can't find a way to do it with Pear DB.

This is what I've started doing, but it is a bit of a pain.

```
$sSql = "SELECT EventID
            DAY(CONVERT_TZ(EventDate, ?, ?)) as EventDay,
            FROM RacingEvents WHERE
            MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(EventDate, ?, ?)) = ? AND
            YEAR(CONVERT_TZ(EventDate, ?, ?)) = ?";

    $aArgs = array();
    $aArgs[] = DEFAULT_TIMEZONE;
    $aArgs[] = $this->sTimezone;
    $aArgs[] = DEFAULT_TIMEZONE;
    $aArgs[] = $this->sTimezone;
    $aArgs[] = $this->iMonth;
    $aArgs[] = DEFAULT_TIMEZONE;
    $aArgs[] = $this->sTimezone;
    $aArgs[] = $this->iYear;

    if ($this->iSkill) {
        $sSql .= " AND NOT REPLACE(EventSkill, ?, '') = EventSkill";
        $aArgs[] = $this->iSkill;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pear's DB package is long dead, and you should either use MDB2 or PDO.

MDB2 supports named parameters that you can pass to `execute()`:

```
<?php
$types = array('integer', 'text', 'text');
$sth = $mdb2->prepare('INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (:id, :name, :lang)', $types);

$data = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'one', 'lang' => 'en');
$affectedRows = $sth->execute($data);
```

Comment: That makes me feel, well, awful. Haha! Looks like I'll be recoding my site that is not even finished yet! Thanks for the heads up